# No-hassle remote debugger for Java that's better than jdb?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging, jdb

I know how to do remote debugging in Java with both jdb and Eclipse.  jdb leaves a lot to be desired in terms of a debugging UI, but there's no "setup" required - just run `jdb -attach ...` and bam you're a-debuggin'.  Eclipse has a much nicer UI, but you have to set up a Java project with a local copy of all the source files, dependency jars, source jars, etc. that's running remotely.

Does there exist any debugging tool with the "lightweight" properties of jdb but which presents you a richer (G)UI?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has these tools integrated (I think they are all just using the jdk versions with a different frontend). I love the remote performance measurements (mosts you can also find in visualvm these days), the remote debugging is a bit more tricky (you need the source in netbeans afterall) but it works. Possibly this is just a frontend for jdb.

Comment: Yeah I took a look at the Netbeans debugger again just now and it looks like you still need all the projects and sources locally, so I wouldn't consider it a big step up from Eclipse. I too love VisualVM.

Comment: You will always need to provide the source files to the debugger, without it a debugger is quiet useless (even though you can do some stuff)

Comment: Uh, that's kinda the point of my question - in jdb you do not need a local copy of all the sources and projects. It displays them from the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Jswat ? http://code.google.com/p/jswat/

Though you'd still want source files locally for convenience
(the JDI protocol sents back file-and-line-numbers; the debugger
can then zoom to that location, in an editor, and highlight..)